# Merging two select queries. Make them unique

Tags: mysql, sql, join, merge

Could someone hint me in the direction of how to merge these two mysql queries?

As you see there is a bug with the distinct too. I need the `topicids` without duplicates and the date for the post from which the `topicid` comes.

I added the `distinct` just to get you an idea of what i need. After getting the `ids` there comes the second query which reads the `topicdetails`...

I am stuck on this.

Get the unique `topicid` from the last n,15 posts for a category, but with the date:

```
SELECT distinct( p.topicid ), p.date as lastaction
FROM posts p 
WHERE p.category = ? 
ORDER BY p.id 
DESC 
LIMIT 
n, 15



SELECT t.id, t.title, t.date, t.state 
FROM topics t 
WHERE t.id in( $var_ids )
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 

p.[topicid],
p.[date] AS lastaction,
t.[id],
t.[title],
t.[date],
t.[state]

FROM posts p 

INNER JOIN topics t
ON p.topicid = t.id


WHERE p.category = /* Enter Category */ AND t.id in ( $var_ids )
ORDER BY p.topicid DESC
```

Use this as a starter for 10. I'm unsure what 'n' is (e.g Column?) so i've left this out

Comment: Hi, this distinct won't work because the date of each post can differ.